# Does toothbrush break your fast?

Tags: practical-islam, sawm

I want to know for maintaining my teeth I need to brush them regularly.
I heard there are ways to brush without breaking your fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A toothbrush can't necessarily break your fast unless you swallow it  ( which I doubt you can do  )

I believe that the question can be edited as to " Does brushing break the fast  ? "

NO unless you swallow the toothpaste, brushing does not break the fast. Take care to brush your teeth without swallowing the toothpaste  ( and water ) .

Islam encourages cleanliness and the Ibadah of a person who is not clean will not be accepted. Therefore it is necessary to clean yourself accordingly.

It is better to use a Miswak following the Sunnah of the Prophet.

Just make sure that nothing touches your throat. ( Even if you inhale water up your nose ) It is said that your fast will be broken even if you swallow a stone  (!).

Cleanliness is next to Godliness

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Astagfirullah how can you ask this question you should not taste any thing and many of the tooth pastes have alcohol in it  and while brushing in normal months when you brush even after gargeling the remaining substance you can taste and feel it in your throat so this thing also goes with tooth brush particles remains on the brush after washing it so using tooth paste in ramadan breaks your fast

Comment: Nice answer thanks

Comment: It is not haram to taste something as long as you have a valid reason to do so when fasting ; in this case the toothpaste. Islam encourages cleanliness , so it would be permissable to use toothpaste.As for alcohol toothpastes, there are plenty of toothpastes in the market which don't contain alcohol :|